# standardController & extensions

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension, standardcontroller

Created a Visual Force Page as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="c_Scrubber" docType="html-5.0">
```

the c_Scrubber.apxc class is constructed as follows:

```
public virtual class c_Scrubber {}
```

I get an error saying:

```
Unknown constructor 'c_Scrubber.c_Scrubber(ApexPages.StandardController controller)'
```

What does thie error mean?  What must be done to resolve it?

Comment: Your naming convention indicates a potential misunderstanding. `c_Scrubber` is not a `controller`. It is an `extension`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class c_Scrubber 
{
   public c_Scrubber (ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

}
}
```

Create class with ApexPages.StandardController constructor as above